# Remove points of polylines that are outside of polygon using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, turfjs

I've draw polyline programmatically (not using leaflet draw) inside polygone using leaflet draw plugin on map, I want to keep only the points of polyline that are inside of polygone and remove those are outside. Do you have any idea how to do that using a leaflet plugin?. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

The expected result:

[image]

I did research on **difference** method of **turf" library as @Sam suggested, so finaly I can apply this method on my drawing polygon and line, here is a code snippet:

```js
var line = path.toGeoJSON();
var polygon = selectedPoly.toGeoJSON();
var difference, result = [];
difference = turf.difference(line, polygon);
if (difference) 
{
    result.push(difference);
    var inter = L.geoJson(result).addTo(map);
}
```

This is a screenshot of the result:

[image]

Now I want to remove this part of line and keep only the section inside polygon, I tried to do that but not working. Can you help me please? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working with [turfjs](http://turfjs.org/) to check for overlapping polygones in leaflet.

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
      var intersection = [];
      otherPolysLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
      if (!_.isUndefined(turf.intersect(e.layer.toGeoJSON(), ))) {
             intersection.push(layer);
      }
   }) 
});
```

You could change the above so that instead it checks for the entire polygone, you'd check with the [difference](http://turfjs.org/docs/#difference) method.

> **difference**: Finds the difference between two polygons by clipping the
>   second polygon from the first.

I've been looking for a good while for a decent library and looked into leaflet-pip, kevlindev amongst others but I find that turf really just works out of the box.

**Update**

http://jsfiddle.net/ddce1wh5/ how about this? I used intersect, because that is apparently the part you'd like to keep, I misread, apologies. The following http://jsfiddle.net/mcqL1y90/ we use an array of lines that uses either the intersecting line, or if no intersection is taking place it takes the line itself to draw on the map.

Comment: Thank you @Sam for your clarification, I wil try to apply **difference** method of **turf** on polyline and polygone. Thanks again

Comment: I'm using Turfjs library as you said @Sam,so until now, I can get difference layer, now I have problem how to remove part of line outside of polygon, I edit the post to add the screeshot and my code snippet

Comment: I can't find solution until now :(

Comment: Hey mate, maybe if you could put up something on jsfiddle.net, that way I could fork what you have so far en see where I might be of assistance?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LnzN2/744/ This is a jsfiddle example, it's not my real code but it's the same issue

Comment: I've updated my answer with my take on your jsfiddle

Comment: Good, it's working, the weird thing is that I already tried using intersect but the problem that I draw the default line and the inresect result :(, nice move. Thank you I can use this for now. During my research I found this post which treat this problem so they are suggesting to develop a new module, here is the link https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/580

Comment: Thank you for the second link, it's useful :)

Comment: It was my pleasure :)