# Get access to each element in object using push in javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet, turfjs

I succeed to get intersection between line and polygon. I had already post this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559669/remove-points-of-polylines-that-are-outside-of-polygon-using-leaflet/42560117?noredirect=1#comment72422008_42560117). Now I'm trying to display result for each line. When I tried to write `console.log(result[i])` I got `undefined`. What is the right syntax I have to do, I tried many times. Here is my current code:

```js
var lines = [line1, line2, line3, line4];
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  var intersection = [];
  var result = [];
  intersection = turf.intersect(lines[i], polygon1);
  if (intersection) {
    result.push(intersection);
    L.geoJson(result, {
      style: Style
    }).addTo(map);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result[i]));
  } else {
    L.geoJson(lines[i]).addTo(map);
  }
```

Comment: The `result` array is useless (an array containing only one element is redundant)! If you want to pass an array to `L.geoJson` that contain the `intersection` element use this: `L.geoJson(  [  intersection  ]  , ...)`! The `var intersection = [];` is redundant too because it get overridden right away with something else!

Comment: you should probably want to tag the question with whatever library you're using so people who know how it works could help!

Comment: Yep @ ibrahim mahrir  you are right, I made many redondance, I update my code, it became more clear now. But still don't know how to fix my issue

Comment: How many Objects `L.geoJson` expect in the array passed in? 1 or more?

Comment: More than one, 4 objects. I can add it all on map, but I don't know how to display data for each one

Comment: I got it, I'll post an answer!

Comment: Thank you, I hope you find the solution

Comment: I can display all this object by writing console.log(intersection), but I want to display only one object, for example interesection between line1 and polygon

Comment: I think it is best that you repost the question and add tags at first so people who know leaflet and turfJs can see it before it get burried and removed from the first page as this one did and people who know leaflet ans turfJs can no longer see it.

Comment: Thank you @ ibrahim mahrir for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You are not iterating over `result`, you are iterating over `lines`, so your `i` index is likely not pointing to the same location in `result` that it is in `lines`. You should just `console.log(intersection)` instead. If you really want/need to display the most recent item you pushed into `result` you could use:

```
console.log(result[result.length - 1]);
```

Comment: Yep I tried this but I want to only display for example intersection betweeb line2 and polygon, I tried to write console.log(intersection[2]) also it's not working. Do you understand my purpose?

Comment: @ Rob M, I tried your code but it return all intersection, not a specific one.