# Get access to each element in object using push Leaflet and turfjs

Tags: leaflet, turfjs

I succeed to get intersection between line and polygon and display it on map. I had already post this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559669/remove-points-of-polylines-that-are-outside-of-polygon-using-leaflet/42560117?noredirect=1#comment72422008_42560117). Now I'm trying to display result for each line on console. When I tried to write `console.log(result[i])` I got `undefined`. What is the right syntax I have to do, I tried many times. Here is my current code:

```js
var lines = [line1, line2, line3, line4];
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  var intersection = [];
  var result = [];
  intersection = turf.intersect(lines[i], polygon1);
  if (intersection) {
    result.push(intersection);
    L.geoJson(result, {
      style: Style
    }).addTo(map);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result[i]));
  } else {
    L.geoJson(lines[i]).addTo(map);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` is being defined inside your for loop which operates over `lines`...so why are you trying to use that loop's internal variable(meant for `lines`) on `result`, which only receives input from turf. I would think you just need `console.log(result[0])`, which would log your intersection.Secondly, I don't see the benefit of calling `JSON.stringify` for that `console.log`.